# eclipse che docker - can not create workspace - <no value>/lib/linux_amd64/terminal

Tags: eclipse, docker, eclipse-che

I tried so set up eclipse che as described in https://eclipse.org/che/docs/setup/docker/
with the following command:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 \
           --name che \
           --rm \
           -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
           -v /myimage \
           eclipse/che-server:5.0.0-latest
```

che runs successfully, but during the creation of the workspace the following error message appears:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.che.api.core.ServerException: Error response from docker API, status: 500, message: create <no va
lue>/lib/linux_amd64/terminal: "<no value>/lib/linux_amd64/terminal" includes invalid characters for a local volume name
, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intented to pass a host directory, use absolute path
```

I experience this both on a debian and on a windows instance. I'm quite new to docker. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker is complaining about the syntax of this:

```
-v /myimage
```

As it's [documented](https://eclipse.org/che/docs/setup/docker/), they recommend to put the /data of che to a volume, in order to persist data between docker runs.

So, put this volume:

```
-v $(pwd)/che-data:/data
```

Resulting in this command:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 \
       --name che \
       --rm \
       -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
       -v $(pwd)/che-data:/data \
       eclipse/che-server:5.0.0-latest
```

`$(pwd)/che-data` is the directory in your host machine where the che's data will be saved.

`/data` is the directory inside che container, linked to ./che-data *outside* container.

Answer (score 2):

I did face the same problem all through and realized that I had done my installations wrong. Following the instructions on the eclipse che website can be quite challenging if you are a newbie to it.

Kindly follow the following steps to install eclipse che using docker image and the issue you are currently facing will be gone.

(The following commands are with the assumption that you are on Debian Distribution. I am on Ubuntu 16.04)

**1. Install JDK on the machine.**

```
$ sudo apt-get update 

$ sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

**2. Install Docker**

```
$ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce
```

**3. Verify if docker has successfully installed**

```
$ systemctl status docker

$ docker -v

$ sudo docker info

$ sudo docker hello-world
```

**4. Install Eclipse CHE**

```
$ cd ~

$ sudo mkdir eclipseche

$ sudo docker run -it --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v ~/eclipseche:/data eclipse/che start
```

Answer (score 0):

-v /myimage \ is wrong :/data is correct